# passing an img through msg

Tags: php

I have a link in a page, if some one click the link a new window will open with list of images.

When user clicks an img it should get inserted into other page.

I am doing some think like this but img is breaking

This is the code of small window 
http://pastebin.com/E8jBzn7y

When user clicks this it should go to othrer page

Can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify in more detail here what goes wrong? What does a generated link look like?

Comment: you can, but like you're trying to .. don't pass markup that way in a url, or it will malfunction for certain.

Comment: The link is invalid, you need to run it through urlencode or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an image that way. Pass the URL instead and use that to display the image.

Comment: You are passing: <img src="images/<?php echo $row['ThirdPartyImageLocation']; ?>. Pass just images/<?php echo $row['ThirdPartyImageLocation']; ?> and create the DOM yourself where you recieve it

Comment: How should i do it? I do n't DOM

Comment: @Tjirp: Nope you can n't pass like that

Comment: Well, you can sort of if a bit silly -> http://www.typingtest.com/testdone.asp?acc=0&nwpm=%3Cimg%20src=%22http://i.somethingawful.com/forumsystem/emoticons/emot-smug.gif%22%3E&gwpm=%3Cimg%20src=%22http://i.somethingawful.com/forumsystem/emoticons/emot-smug.gif%22%3E&ncpm=0&gcpm=0&dur=60&time=0&chksum=13&unit=wpm&kh=999&td=&err=0&hits=0

Comment: @Tjirp:  I fixed the bug , this is the answer  <a href="newcategory.php?msg11=<img src=images/<?php echo $category;?> alt="image" border="0" "/> <img src="images/<?php echo $row['ThirdPartyImageLocation']; ?>" /></a>